# Detail View Controller transition from Master View Contoller

Tags: swift

I am getting "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" because in my code below I am trying to assign value to webview before its initialize. I am trying to transition from Master to Detail view controller.

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Detail View Code:

```
  var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detailContent = detailItem?.valueForKey("content") as? String{
            self.webView.loadHTMLString(detailContent as String, baseURL:nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.configureView()
    }
```

It is failing because my Webview in Nil. How do I come around this situation where my outlets are not initialized while setting them.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop and think about the order in which things happen:

- `prepareForSegue` - The destination view controller exists, but that's all. It has no view and its outlets have not been set. You can set its non-outlet properties but that's all you can do.
- The segue starts to happen.
- The destination view controller gets `viewDidLoad`. *Now* it has a view and its outlets are set.
- The segue completes and the destination view controller gets `viewWillAppear:` and later, `viewDidAppear:`. Now its view is actually in the interface.

So clearly you cannot permit `configureView` to *assume* that the web view exists, because the first time it is called, namely in `prepareForSegue`, it *doesn't* exist. `configureView` needs to test explicitly whether `self.webView` is nil, and if it is, it should do nothing:

```
func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if self.webView == nil { return } // no web view, bail out
    if let detailContent = detailItem?.valueForKey("content") as? String{
        self.webView.loadHTMLString(detailContent as String, baseURL:nil)
    }
}
```

After that, everything will be fine. `viewDidLoad` will subsequently be called, and `configureView` will be called *again* - and *this* time, both `detailItem` and the web view exist, so all will be well.

Comment: thanks you so much for your explanation. It help me have better understanding.