# Swift : non-nil optional value raising a nil exception

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I'm having a dictionary, with values, i'm calling it to populate a field

```
  if let userdata: NSDictionary = self.fbdata {
    println(userdata["email"]) // print Optional(email@domain.com)
    vc.email.text = userdata["email"] as? String ?? "" // raise a nil error
  }
```

As put in the code, the userdata["email"] exists and has a value, printed by println, anyway at the next line i have a nil optional exception raised (and even the default "" value isn't used)

I don't see what i'm doing wrong here

Comment: Are `vc` or `vc.email` nil?

Comment: arg, you're right, i was focused on the dictionary. Well the vc.email isn't supposed to be nil, it's an outlet to a textfield but it seems to not unwrap in the prepareForSegue function...

Comment: Check IBoutlet for email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it's an outlet to a textfield but it seems to not unwrap in the prepareForSegue function

That comment reveals your misconception. Things happen in a order, which I discuss here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29552710/341994

So, by design, `prepareForSegue` happens *before* the new view controller has its view - or its outlets. Conversely, the first moment when its outlets are connected is its own `viewDidLoad`, which is later.

Your real mistake, though, is deeper. One view controller has *no business* setting or talking to another view controller's outlets and thus manipulating its interface. Instead, set things up so that the destination view controller has an ordinary *property* which you can set. In `viewDidLoad`, that view controller than checks that property, retrieves the value, and sets its *own* interface through its outlet.

So, to sum up: `prepareForSegue` is your chance to initialize the new view controller. But that's all. The new view controller will then later control its own view — as the name implies! And it will do this starting in its own `viewDidLoad` and later.

Comment: You're right, i was totally wrong. I'm new in iOS and need to improve. Thanks for your time to show me where i was wrong and point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hear hear! You should treat a view controller's view hierarchy as private. Mucking around with a view controller's views is a serious violation of the OOP principle of [**encapsulation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)).